# C# WinForms Chart Coloring horizontal grid cells

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, charts

I'm showing a chart which represents audio frequency data. However it is pretty unclear to look at now. The image shows the current chart. Is there a way to make the chart appear as it does on the right so it looks more like a piano roll rather than a simple chart?
[image: Left (current) Right (wanted]

Comment: Yes. You can create [Striplines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.stripline(v=vs.110).aspx) . [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775533/line-chart-with-different-colors-on-a-different-interval-at-x-axis-fill-in-same/50113664#50113664) In your case use repeating ones!

Comment: @TaW Thanks for the tip. I had to use 5 different ones though, each repeating every once every octave.

Comment: Glad to hear it works. For regular intervals one with the right width and interval will be enough but keyboards are special indeed.. I missed that part, sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using 5 striplines with different offset for each black key on the keyboard.

```
private void AddStriplines() {

        lineIntervalOffsets = new double[5] {1, 3, 6, 8, 10 };

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            StripLine line = StriplineConfig();
            Area.AxisY.StripLines.Add(line);
        }

    }
    private StripLine StriplineConfig() {
        StripLine line = new StripLine();
        line.BorderColor = Color.DarkGray;
        line.Interval = 12;
        return line;
    }
```